# How to test if an error occurred on the Server, and output client side

Tags: java, servlets, download

Okay, so I've been working on this for a few days, and I've hit something of an issue. Basically, the idea is simple. The user clicks a link, and this sends a request to the server to generate a PDF document. This isn't downloaded per se. It is sent back to the browser in the form of an attachment.

The issue is simple. If something goes wrong in generating the PDF document, I don't want the browser to attempt to download the file. Now what I've got in motion at the moment is simple.

```
  if(req.getParameterMap().containsKey("report")) {
            if(req.getParameter("report").equals("true"))
            {
                // If the query string parameter is set, generate the PDF.
                if(!PdfReportGenerator.generateReport(res, repositoryURI)) {
                    // Something went wrong, so redirect the browser.
                    res.sendRedirect(req.getRequestURI());
                }
            }
        }
```

At the moment, what this does is re-direct the user back to the page they're already on. In short, nothing happens. Now this is okay-ish, but I'd rather have some nice browser feedback. The one method I can think of at the moment is just appending `"?error=pdf` or something along those lines onto the end of the URL, but it is possible the user will have other functionality that requires query strings.

My question is, is there a way, other than a query string, to send a message back to the browser when downloading an attachment, that an error has occurred. I'm open to any suggestions; I imagine `Javascript` is going to be the language of choice here.

Comment: No need for javascript. These types of messages are commonly known as _flash messages_. Basically, the idea is that - inside of your controller - you set a _flash message_ on the user's session. Then - generally in your view layer - you print out any flash messages that are present in the session, and subsequently remove them from the session.

Comment: Are there any tutorials on this, because I'm still quite stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this simple solution for you...

```
if(req.getParameter("report").equals("true"))
{
  req.getSession().setAttrinute("REPORT_OK",false);
  //If the query string parameter is set, generate the PDF.
  if(!PdfReportGenerator.generateReport(res, repositoryURI)) {
    // Something went wrong, so redirect the browser.
    res.sendRedirect(req.getRequestURI());
  }else{
    req.getSession().setAttrinute("REPORT_OK",true);
  }
}
```

Now in your RequestURI page have a [document.ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function to check with [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) about the state of the `REPORT_OK` variable.

Case 1: If the value is `null` that means that the request in not a callback from your code above, so you don't display anything to the user.

Case 2: If the value is `false`, then that means than an error happened and you can inform the user about it.

Case 3: If the value is `true`, then generation of pdf is successful and you should inform the user accordingly.

Don't forget to remove the attribute from session after you check it with ajax so that when you refresh the page, or revisit it, the ajax will go to Case 1.

**UPDATE**

How to make the ajax call :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divToChange = $('#message');//div id of the message you show to user
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'checkReport.jsp',
    data: {},
    beforeSend:function(){
        divToChange.html('Loading...');
    },
    success:function(data){
        divToChange.html(data);
    },
    error:function(){
        divToChange.html('Checking file failed!');
    }
  });
)};
```

And now on your `checkReport.jsp` :

```
<%
Boolean status = (Boolean) session.getAttribute("REPORT_OK");
if(status==null){
    //dont return anything
}else if(status){
    out.print("Report is ok");
}else {
    out.print("Report generation failed ");
}
%>
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution! I'm still a little stuck on how I can use AJAX to request the `REPORT_OK` attribute?

Comment: Sorry. This hasn't worked for me at all. This assumes an awful lot about the structure of the project, and I don't think it's going to work for me, HOWEVER it seems like a good general answer, so I can mark it as correct.